# how to sort mysql result set after the query's done

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am writing a query for mysql database having 2 parameters.

Its a basic search but the problem is I want to sort the order of the results on the basis of the selection.
So after I've clicked the *search* button and the browser displayied the result set I want to order this specific result set by *expiration-date* or by *price* depending wich button i click.

```
   //SELECTION DATA FORM 
   <form action="EVENTS_SELECTION.PHP">
     <select name="Type">
     <option value="">SPORT
     <option value="">CULTURE       
     <option value="">LEISURE
     <option value="">GASTRONOMY
     </select>  

     <select name="WHERE">
     <option>ROME ALL
     <option>ROME SOUTH
     <option>ROME WEST
     <option>ROME EAST
     <option>ROME NORTH
     </select>

     <input type="submit" value="search">   
 </form>
```

how can I achieve that??
thanks
Luca

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort your results in the html page, without submitting? Or do you want to write the results to your page in a certain order? Also, where's your result set? I only see what looks like a search form.

Comment: I would say redo the search query, see for example ajax. How will you handle the limit-things of you results, don't you think the database is the right place to do the limitations & sort things?

Comment: just run another query with additional ORDER BY clause

Comment: redo the search query..but how i do make php remember the previous parameters?..lets say I searched for "ALL EVENTS type SPORT in ROME SOUTH".Now I have all of them paginated in a default order;I go clicking on "sort by price" :i need to redo the previous query (select all events type sport in rome south)plus the "ORDER BY PRICE" command..how can I achieve that?

Comment: just pass it to PHP again. add all these parameters to the sorting link

Comment: i dont understand how i can pass them dinamically.. sorry =(

Comment: Do your sorting in the database query.  You can either reload the page, likely passing sort criteria as parameters, or investigate AJAX functionality to do table sorting (the are a number of javascript libraries (including jQuery plug-ins) that can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort after search you can use [usort()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function:

```
function myComparer($a, $b)
{
    if ($GLOBALS['SEARCH_TYPE'] == 'PRICE')
    {
        $valueA = floatval($a['price']);
        $valueB = floatval($b['price']);
    }
    else ($GLOBALS['SEARCH_TYPE'] == 'EXPIRATION-DATE')
    {
        // time string to UNIX timestamp integer value
        $valueA = strtotime($a['expiration_date']);
        $valueB = strtotime($b['expiration_date']);
    }

    if ($valueA == $valueB) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($valueA < $valueB) ? -1 : 1;
}

include './get_search_type.php';
// is stored in array $GLOBALS['SEARCH_TYPE']

include './get_search_result.php'; xyz is the field name
// is stored in array $GLOBALS['SEARCH_RESULT'][xyz]

usort($GLOBALS['SEARCH_RESULT'], myComparer);
```

btw: In my opinion it is better to generate a dynamic query to sort by DBMS (thats much easier):

```
if ($GLOBALS['SEARCH_TYPE'] == 'PRICE')
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY price;";
}
else ($GLOBALS['SEARCH_TYPE'] == 'EXPIRATION-DATE')
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY expiration_date;";
}
```

Comment: that's quite inefficient way to alter a query by typing whole query string as many times as many search variants we have. Why not to change order by part only? And $GLOBALS variable has no use here, it's rather $_GET should be.

Answer (score 0):

[Server Side]
Store php query result into an array like below:

```
// if you want to sort by column 'name', store them by format: $dataset[{pid}] = {name};
// pid  name
//  1   test1
//  2   alpha1
//  5   candy1
while (...) // read query result
{
    $dataset[$row['pid']] = new array($row['name'] => $row);
}    
// now, use sort()
sort($dataset);

// then foreach array to get sorted data;
foreach ($datasetas $key => $val) {
    echo $val."\n";
}
```

[Client Side]
Read data and store them by JSON format and response. Then, in your page, use javascript json library to sort them.

Comment: And what's the use of this array after page already was displayed to the user?!

Comment: it let me know sort of name, and after sorting, array index will be sorted pid(by name column sorting). I edit my code, like that.

Comment: By Mike says, server side solution is for post-display. Client side solution is used for AJAX, like ExtJS's Store component. BTW, I suggest AJAX with JSON to sort at client side.

Comment: I think this is a better solution. You don't need to put more load on the web-server and the sql-server if you already have the results. It's just a matter of displaying something differently, and that's a job for Javascript. Unless, the list is so big that response time + query execution time is smaller than javascript sorting time, which I doubt will ever happen in a good interface.

Comment: Agree Mike says. And if your list is more big, you can take it into paging mode with AJAX.

Comment: @Mike this solution has a very small disadvantage. **It will never work.**

Comment: @Shrapnel why would that be? You have the data, you can sort it. Maybe this specific code won't work, but then again, the OP did not specify how he wants data to be shown so...

Comment: **YOU DON'T HAVE THE DATA!** It's dead. That's the way PHP works, and you'd better to start learning that.